# Create Sphinx wordforms from aspell

Tags: sphinx, aspell

Is there possibility to create wordforms for sphinx from aspell?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Aspell, but it looks easy to dump a dictionary

http://aspell.net/0.50-doc/man-html/5_Working.html

From there should be trivial to convert that file to a wordforms file.